# Magento 2 Get cart detail API doesn't show subtotal and total

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, subtotal

```
Cart API url

http://magento.host/rest/V1/carts/mine/

Authorization <Customer Token>
```

- This API provided Lists items that are assigned to a specified cart.
- But Not **Subtotal and Total price of items** that are assigned to a
  specified cart.

How to get **sub-total and total price of items** that are assigned to specified cart In **REST API using Customer Token ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**quoteCartTotalRepositoryV1**

Interface CartTotalRepositoryInterface

```
GET /V1/carts/mine/totals
```

**Returns quote totals data for a specified cart.**

> Response data

```
{
  "grandTotal": 0,
  "baseGrandTotal": 0,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "baseSubtotal": 0,
  "discountAmount": 0,
  "baseDiscountAmount": 0,
  "subtotalWithDiscount": 0,
  "baseSubtotalWithDiscount": 0,
  "shippingAmount": 0,
  "baseShippingAmount": 0,
  "shippingDiscountAmount": 0,
  "baseShippingDiscountAmount": 0,
  "taxAmount": 0,
  "baseTaxAmount": 0,
  "weeeTaxAppliedAmount": 0,
  "shippingTaxAmount": 0,
  "baseShippingTaxAmount": 0,
  "subtotalInclTax": 0,
  "baseSubtotalInclTax": 0,
  "shippingInclTax": 0,
  "baseShippingInclTax": 0,
  "baseCurrencyCode": "string",
  "quoteCurrencyCode": "string",
  "couponCode": "string",
  "itemsQty": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "basePrice": 0,
      "qty": 0,
      "rowTotal": 0,
      "baseRowTotal": 0,
      "rowTotalWithDiscount": 0,
      "taxAmount": 0,
      "baseTaxAmount": 0,
      "taxPercent": 0,
      "discountAmount": 0,
      "baseDiscountAmount": 0,
      "discountPercent": 0,
      "priceInclTax": 0,
      "basePriceInclTax": 0,
      "rowTotalInclTax": 0,
      "baseRowTotalInclTax": 0,
      "options": "string",
      "weeeTaxAppliedAmount": 0,
      "weeeTaxApplied": "string",
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "totalSegments": [
    {
      "code": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "value": 0,
      "area": "string",
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "taxGrandtotalDetails": [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "rates": [
              {
                "percent": "string",
                "title": "string"
              }
            ],
            "groupId": 0
          }
        ],
        "giftCards": "string",
        "gwOrderId": "string",
        "gwItemIds": [
          "string"
        ],
        "gwAllowGiftReceipt": "string",
        "gwAddCard": "string",
        "gwPrice": "string",
        "gwBasePrice": "string",
        "gwItemsPrice": "string",
        "gwItemsBasePrice": "string",
        "gwCardPrice": "string",
        "gwCardBasePrice": "string",
        "gwBaseTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwItemsBaseTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwItemsTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwCardBaseTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwCardTaxAmount": "string",
        "gwPriceInclTax": "string",
        "gwBasePriceInclTax": "string",
        "gwCardPriceInclTax": "string",
        "gwCardBasePriceInclTax": "string",
        "gwItemsPriceInclTax": "string",
        "gwItemsBasePriceInclTax": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "extensionAttributes": {
    "rewardPointsBalance": 0,
    "rewardCurrencyAmount": 0,
    "baseRewardCurrencyAmount": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To collect totals for cart based on shipping/payment methods and additional data. Use this

> PUT /V1/carts/mine/collect-totals

Implementation Notes:

Set shipping/billing methods and additional data for cart and collect totals.

Parameters :

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
    "po_number": "string",
    "method": "string",
    "additional_data": [
      "string"
    ],
    "extension_attributes": {
      "agreement_ids": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  "shippingCarrierCode": "string",
  "shippingMethodCode": "string",
  "additionalData": {
    "extension_attributes": {
      "gift_messages": [
        {
          "gift_message_id": 0,
          "customer_id": 0,
          "sender": "string",
          "recipient": "string",
          "message": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {
            "entity_id": "string",
            "entity_type": "string",
            "wrapping_id": 0,
            "wrapping_allow_gift_receipt": true,
            "wrapping_add_printed_card": true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "grand_total": 0,
  "base_grand_total": 0,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "base_subtotal": 0,
  "discount_amount": 0,
  "base_discount_amount": 0,
  "subtotal_with_discount": 0,
  "base_subtotal_with_discount": 0,
  "shipping_amount": 0,
  "base_shipping_amount": 0,
  "shipping_discount_amount": 0,
  "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
  "tax_amount": 0,
  "base_tax_amount": 0,
  "weee_tax_applied_amount": 0,
  "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
  "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
  "subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
  "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 0,
  "shipping_incl_tax": 0,
  "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
  "base_currency_code": "string",
  "quote_currency_code": "string",
  "coupon_code": "string",
  "items_qty": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "base_price": 0,
      "qty": 0,
      "row_total": 0,
      "base_row_total": 0,
      "row_total_with_discount": 0,
      "tax_amount": 0,
      "base_tax_amount": 0,
      "tax_percent": 0,
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "base_discount_amount": 0,
      "discount_percent": 0,
      "price_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_price_incl_tax": 0,
      "row_total_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_row_total_incl_tax": 0,
      "options": "string",
      "weee_tax_applied_amount": 0,
      "weee_tax_applied": "string",
      "extension_attributes": {
        "negotiable_quote_item_totals": {
          "cost": 0,
          "catalog_price": 0,
          "base_catalog_price": 0,
          "catalog_price_incl_tax": 0,
          "base_catalog_price_incl_tax": 0,
          "cart_price": 0,
          "base_cart_price": 0,
          "cart_tax": 0,
          "base_cart_tax": 0,
          "cart_price_incl_tax": 0,
          "base_cart_price_incl_tax": 0,
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      },
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "total_segments": [
    {
      "code": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "value": 0,
      "area": "string",
      "extension_attributes": {
        "tax_grandtotal_details": [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "rates": [
              {
                "percent": "string",
                "title": "string"
              }
            ],
            "group_id": 0
          }
        ],
        "gift_cards": "string",
        "gw_order_id": "string",
        "gw_item_ids": [
          "string"
        ],
        "gw_allow_gift_receipt": "string",
        "gw_add_card": "string",
        "gw_price": "string",
        "gw_base_price": "string",
        "gw_items_price": "string",
        "gw_items_base_price": "string",
        "gw_card_price": "string",
        "gw_card_base_price": "string",
        "gw_base_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_items_base_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_items_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_card_base_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_card_tax_amount": "string",
        "gw_price_incl_tax": "string",
        "gw_base_price_incl_tax": "string",
        "gw_card_price_incl_tax": "string",
        "gw_card_base_price_incl_tax": "string",
        "gw_items_price_incl_tax": "string",
        "gw_items_base_price_incl_tax": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "extension_attributes": {
    "coupon_label": "string",
    "base_customer_balance_amount": 0,
    "customer_balance_amount": 0,
    "negotiable_quote_totals": {
      "items_count": 0,
      "quote_status": "string",
      "created_at": "string",
      "updated_at": "string",
      "customer_group": 0,
      "base_to_quote_rate": 0,
      "cost_total": 0,
      "base_cost_total": 0,
      "original_total": 0,
      "base_original_total": 0,
      "original_tax": 0,
      "base_original_tax": 0,
      "original_price_incl_tax": 0,
      "base_original_price_incl_tax": 0,
      "negotiated_price_type": 0,
      "negotiated_price_value": 0
    },
    "reward_points_balance": 0,
    "reward_currency_amount": 0,
    "base_reward_currency_amount": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: This is PUT method, It should be GET without passing any data just like mine/cart

Comment: This returns no- route error

Comment: It means This named API doesn't exists.

Comment: Changing from PUT to GET does not work :)